# How to split a string from the right side

Tags: ruby, string

How can I split a string from right side by `','`? From this string:

```
str_a = "#37/1, New Ray Street, 24th mains,2nd cross, Bangalore Karnataka India"
```

I want an output:

```
"#37/1, New Ray Street, 24th mains,2nd cross"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`String#rpartition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-rpartition):

```
str_a = "#37/1, New Ray Street, 24th mains,2nd cross, Bangalore Karnataka India"
str_a.rpartition(',')
# => ["#37/1, New Ray Street, 24th mains,2nd cross", ",", " Bangalore Karnataka India"]
str_a.rpartition(',')[0]
# => "#37/1, New Ray Street, 24th mains,2nd cross"
```

**UPDATE**

If `str_a` does not contain `,`, the above code will return the empty string. Use following code if that could be an issue.

```
str_a = "#37/1"
head, sep, tail = str_a.rpartition(',') # => ["", "", "#37/1"]
sep == '' ? tail : head # OR   sep[0] ? head : tail
# => "#37/1"
```

Comment: much better than what I was going to suggest: `str_a.reverse.split(",").map(&:reverse).drop(1).reverse.join`

Comment: @ Austin Lin, here all ',' 's will go off like #37/ New Ray Street 24th mains 2nd cross

Comment: @RajeshGurbani, No `,` goes off.

Answer (score 0):

While @falsetru suggestion is fairly the best if you *know* what the input string format is, it will return empty string if there were no commas in the input at all. Simple regexp

```
str_a.gsub /,[^,]*$/, ''
```

will return the input string intouch in such a case. Plus you have an ability to modify your input *inplace* with `gsub!`.